# OnClickListener in ListView with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with a custom adapter that inflates a layout. The layout that the adapter inflates contains multiple buttons in it. My goal is to inflate this layout for each item in the custom adapter and have the buttons that correspond to that layout respond only for the layout that it is in (the listview item position that it is located). Here is the code for my custom adapter:

```
    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private final Context context;
    private List<String> viewContent;
    //private List<String> posts;
    private List<String> posts;

    int index = 0;
    String title;
    TextView testText;

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings, List<String> content) {
        super(context, R.layout.post_layout, strings);
        this.context = context;
        this.posts = strings;
        this.viewContent = content;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View postLayout, final ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        positionHolder = position;
        Log.i("Position", "" + position);

        if(postLayout == null) {
            Log.i("CONVERTVIEW", "Convert View is null");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            postLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);


            viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper)postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
            viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
            viewHolder.fillSpace = (TextView)postLayout.findViewById(R.id.posthelpSpace);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postProfPic);
            viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
            viewHolder.eventImage = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
            viewHolder.likesTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.likesTV);
            viewHolder.planToAttendTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.planToAttendTV);
            viewHolder.addressTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postLocationTV);
            viewHolder.addToCalendarButton = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarButton);
            viewHolder.addToCalConfirm = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarConfirmedButton);
            viewHolder.postImageVF = (ViewFlipper) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postBackgroundHolderVF);
            viewHolder.eventMap = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.location_map);
            viewHolder.detailsButton = (ImageButton) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailsButton);
            viewHolder.detailsButtonHelp = (Button) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailsButtonHelp);
            viewHolder.descriptionTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postEventDescription);
            viewHolder.showInfoButton = (Button) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.showinfobutton);
            viewHolder.eventInfoVF = (ViewFlipper) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.eventInfoVF);

            postLayout.setTag(viewHolder);
            String objectItem = viewContent.get(position);
            viewHolder.addToCalVF.setTag(objectItem);


        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) postLayout.getTag();
            //viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper)
        }

            viewHolder.addToCalVF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((ViewFlipper)view).showNext();
                    Log.i("VIEWFLIPPERVF", viewHolder.addToCalVF.toString());
                }
            });



            viewHolder.unameTV.setText(adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(0).toString());
            Log.i("POSTLISTS", adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(0).get(0).toString());
            Log.i("POSTLISTS", adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(1).get(0).toString());


        viewHolder.unameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        Profile.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                String username = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                in.putExtra("username", username);
                Log.i("Username", "" + username);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

            viewHolder.fillSpace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    View relayout = lv.getChildAt(0);
                    viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                    String username = viewHolder.unameTV.getText().toString();

                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            Profile.class);
                    // sending pid to next activity
                    in.putExtra("username", username);
                    Log.i("Username", "" + username);

                    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
            });




            DisplayImageOptions options = initiateDisplayImageOptions();
            viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    View relayout = lv.getChildAt(0);
                    viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                    String username = viewHolder.unameTV.getText().toString();

                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            Profile.class);
                    // sending pid to next activity
                    in.putExtra("username", username);
                    Log.i("Username", "" + username);

                    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
            });

            ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            initImageLoader(getActivity());
            imageloader.displayImage(adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(1).toString(), viewHolder.image, options);



        viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setText(adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(2).toString());
        viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar startCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                startCal.setTime(new Date());
                startCal.set(STARTYEARS.get(position), STARTMONTHS.get(position), STARTDAYS.get(position), STARTHOURS.get(position), STARTMINS.get(position));


                Calendar endCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                endCal.setTime(new Date());
                endCal.set(ENDYEARS.get(position), ENDMONTHS.get(position), ENDDAYS.get(position), ENDHOURS.get(position), ENDMINS.get(position));

                String id = Double.toString(EventUtils.assignName());

                View relayout;
                try {
                    relayout = lv.getChildAt(1);
                    viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                    title = viewHolder.eventTitle.getText().toString();

                    addEvent(id, title, startCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis(), position);

                    viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                    viewHolder.addToCalVF.showNext();

                    Log.i("VIEWFLIPPER", viewHolder.addToCalVF.toString());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException np)
                {
                    relayout = lv.getChildAt(0);
                    viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                    title = viewHolder.eventTitle.getText().toString();

                    addEvent(id, title, startCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis(), position);

                    viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                    viewHolder.addToCalVF.showNext();

                    Log.i("VIEWFLIPPER", viewHolder.addToCalVF.toString());

                }

            }
        });





            viewHolder.eventTitle.setText(adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(3).toString());


            testText = viewHolder.eventTitle;
            imageloader.displayImage(adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(4).toString(), viewHolder.eventImage, options);


            viewHolder.likesTV.setText("" + adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(5).toString());

            viewHolder.planToAttendTV.setText(adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(6).toString());

            viewHolder.addressTV.setText("" + adapterUtilities.POSTSLISTS.get(position).get(7).toString());
            viewHolder.addressTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    viewHolder.detailsButton.performClick();
                }
            });



            viewHolder.addToCalConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    View relayout;
                    try {

                        relayout = lv.getChildAt(1);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF.showNext();

                        viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                        title = viewHolder.eventTitle.getText().toString();
                        DeleteCalendarEntry(EVENTIDS.get(position), title);
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException np)
                    {
                        relayout = lv.getChildAt(0);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF.showNext();

                        viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                        title = viewHolder.eventTitle.getText().toString();
                        DeleteCalendarEntry(EVENTIDS.get(position), title);
                    }



                }
            });


        viewHolder.detailsButtonHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewHolder.detailsButton.performClick();
            }
        });




        viewHolder.detailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



            }
        });





        viewHolder.showInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("POSITIONINVIEW", "" + lv.getLastVisiblePosition());

                View relayout;
                try {
                    relayout = lv.getChildAt(1);
                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.eventInfoVF);
                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                            R.anim.push_up_in));
                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                            R.anim.push_down_out));

                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF.showNext();
                }
                catch (NullPointerException np)
                {
                    relayout = lv.getChildAt(0);
                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.eventInfoVF);
                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                            R.anim.push_up_in));
                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                            R.anim.push_down_out));

                    viewHolder.eventInfoVF.showNext();
                }
            }
        });


        return postLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return posts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return posts.get(position);
    }

     class ViewHolder {
         ImageView image;
         TextView addToCalendarButton;
         TextView eventTitle;
         ImageView eventImage;
         ImageView eventMap;
         TextView likesTV;
         TextView planToAttendTV;
         TextView addressTV;
         TextView unameTV;
         TextView descriptionTV;
         TextView fillSpace;
         ImageButton detailsButton;
         Button detailsButtonHelp;
         Button showInfoButton;

         TextView addToCalConfirm;
         ViewFlipper addToCalVF;
         ViewFlipper postImageVF;
         ViewFlipper eventInfoVF;

     }

}
```

From what I understand, with the custom adapter the position of the item that is visible on the screen is considered as position 0 with the one that comes after it being position 1. I test this by populating the listview with 3 items so 3 layouts are inflated into the listview. However when I click any button on the layout, the correct action happens however it also happens for the layout located 1 item away from the desired layout. So when I click a button in the layout located in the listview at position 0, the same action happens for the layout located in the listview at position 2 and vice versa when I select an button in listview position 2. I am trying to make each listview item behave independently and correctly for each specific position but I have not been able to come about the answer myself or on the internet. How do I correctly add an onclicklistener in a custom adapter which makes the view behave appropriately for its desired position? Much like how a Instagrams like button only "likes" the desired picture?

Comment: @MDroid The issue is that more than one listview item responds to a button click when only one item is supposed to respond

Comment: `the position of the item that is visible on the screen is considered as position 0` ? You mean the first visible item ? No that is wrong. Position 0 is the first item in the array of the array adapter. Further, if you have only three items you cannot test your code for correctness. You should have lots of items so the user can scroll up and down along a long list.

Comment: @greenapps upon using your suggestion of adding more content, the problem exists still just on the predicted, larger scale. Whenever I click a button in the layout located in listview position 0, the items that respond are 0, 2, 4 , 6, and 8. Same with selecting the item in position 1. The items that respond are 1, 3, 5 ,7 and 9.

Comment: Which buttons are you talking about. Names please.

Comment: @greenapps all of them. The problem root I believe lies somewhere in how I get the selected view in the try statement of each buttons onclick listener.

Comment: `Log.i("POSITIONINVIEW", "" + lv.getLastVisiblePosition());` That will not be true is it?

Comment: All of them? I asked for names.

Comment: @greenapps to elaborate on all of them, almost all of the widgets in the viewHolder have onClickListeners. Each view with an onClickListener has this problem.

Comment: That's unreadable. Anyhow indeed the code in for instance the info button is wrong as you use viewHolder variable. That is most certainly the wrong viewHolder at the time the user clicks the item. You have to determine the right view holdet first from some Tag. You probably made viewHolder final to be able to use it in on click. Remove the final. Then you see where you have to code it different.

Comment: @greenapps thank you for your responses. But if you are still willing to help perhaps we should move this to a discussion.

Comment: No. But recently i helped someone with the same problem. Maybe it was even this morning. I will post a link tomorrow so you can benefit.

Comment: `ViewHolder viewHolder;` Put that in getView() as you can only use it there. (You did not make it final, but this is no good either).

Comment: @greenapps the link will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866922/listview-scrolling-issue-on-item-selection/25867177