# How to expand and collapse an item in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am pretty new to android. I want to implement a list view. It contains some list items and when they are clicked, they should expand showing more information. But I unable to find a way to do that

Here is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="True"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:padding="7dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`listview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/expand_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to populate the `textview2` to show more info. Below is my `main_activity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    String[] titles;
    String[] desc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.text_info);
        desc = res.getStringArray(R.array.text_desc);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listview, R.id.textView1, titles);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">ListView</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string-array name="text_info">
    <item>Tutorial 1</item>
    <item>Tutorial 2</item>
    <item>Tutorial 3</item>
    <item>Tutorial 4</item>
    <item>Tutorial 5</item>
    <item>Tutorial 6</item>
    <item>Tutorial 7</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="text_desc">
    <item>Tutorial 1</item>
    <item>Tutorial 2</item>
    <item>Tutorial 3</item>
    <item>Tutorial 4</item>
    <item>Tutorial 5</item>
    <item>Tutorial 6</item>
    <item>Tutorial 7</item>
</string-array>

<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/expand_icon"` I only see this now. And i see it in two states in the picture. What kind of icon is this? Have you added code in order to change state at click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to set the visibility of the second textview to View.GONE and View.VISIBLE when the user clicks the item. Implement an OnItemClickListener first. Using an ExpandableListView for this simple task is overkill.

In your OnItemClick handler:

```
            TextView textView = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            if ( textView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)             
                {
                //expandedChildList.set(arg2, true);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            else
                {
                //expandedChildList.set(arg2, false);
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for ur suggestion. Can u provide with some reference so that i can go through that

Comment: OnItemClickListeners for a ListView have been posted here many times as it is pretty basic stuff. So with a little search you should find one. Then try and post your code here if you have questions.

Comment: Guess i am confused.. Can u help me with a sample code snippet?

Comment: `Your listView will never expand showing description if you follow this method` Did you try? Well i implemented it and use it and it works ok.

Comment: `Then try and post your code here if you have questions`.

Comment: I got stuck here

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    
    
   }
  });

Comment: I really dnt understand how to do that

Comment: @greenapps Can u help me with a small code snippet on how to go about with the onitemclicklistener? That would help me a lot

Comment: You can read all here: Instead of setting the color of the whole view to normal and selected you will adapt the code a bit to set the visibility of the second textview of the view in two states. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866922/listview-scrolling-issue-on-item-selection/25867177 Try again and post your code (not in a comment) but in your post.

Comment: As a little gimmick: Just put `arg2.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in the listener. :-). Try that first. report what happens please.

Comment: Ofcourse not. Not on an int. Only on a View. So excuse my typo. Use arg1.

Comment: Yeah... the title "Tutorial 1" and so on gets disappeared when the list item is clicked

Comment: Mmm.. it is a little bit different as i had expected. I tried for myself and indeed the view gets emptied but does not disappear. I posted new code.

Comment: @greenapps : Thanks a lot.. I just need to populate the textview2. thanks for ur effort.. I troubled u i guess

Comment: Not at all. But you are not done yet.. If you have a lot of items you can scroll the list up and down. Do that and see that it does not keep state. But maybe that's no problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use ExpandableListview instead of simple ListView.

Updated

Follow this tutorial and it will help you https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbP2HeYGC3kfHjHLMPplZuQ
he'll teach you how to use ListView using BaseAdapter and this will grow your confidence to implement ExpandableListView on your own..

Answer (score 1):

There is ExpandableListView to call try this
https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial