# Listview in dialog with header and footer

Tags: android, listview, android-dialog

I have a listview in my dialog and then I have to use the header layout and footer layout. the way I am doing it , aligning my header layout to top and the footer layout to bottom . but it has a problem. take a look at below picture ..
[image: Dialog with the list inside with header and footer]

**But by doing that the dialog gets Longer in size which is not expected**

I am traped in this situation. Well If i align my footer with the listview end then the footer gets out of the screen. which is also not expected.

> **What I want :**

- I want that My listview should be visible in the center of dialog with the header layout align top and the footer layout align to the bootm of the dialog botttom border and it should not take the full length of the screen.
- Isnt there a way to align the footer to the bottom of the dialog and dialog it self maintain its height (Note: I do not want to give the dialog hard coded height as I want the dialog to be look same on all devices. )

Please help I am stuck in the situation. If we look at the google dialog whcih comes while installing the app, it has short dialog with the listview in center of it and buttons are aligning to bottom of the dialog. How they are doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the dynamic solution for your problem..
Sample dialog xml file name `activity_list_test.xml`..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/page_bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header Button" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvCommon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bottom Button" /></LinearLayout>`
```

Here's the calling from a fragment/activity where you want..

```
private void showAlert() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_test, null);
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setTitle(null);
    dialog.setMessage(null);

    ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        mList.add("ABC");
    }


    ListView lvCommon = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvCommon);

    int deviceHeight = getScreenSize(getActivity()).y;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, deviceHeight / 3,1f);
    lvCommon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    lvCommon.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

There device height will be auto measure and according to it the dialog size will be `"deviceheight/3"`..so it will be maintain in all devices..

Now you need the method `getScreenSize`..So here's it is::

```
 public static Point getScreenSize(Activity act) {
    int screenWidth = 0;
    int screenHeight = 0;

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    return new Point(screenWidth, screenHeight);

}
```

Comment: promising ,, i ll try

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout to your `Dialog` like below way

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/header_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header Text"
        android:gravity="center|top"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/footer_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer Text"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It will set `Header View to Top`,`ListView to Center` and `Footer View to Bottom`

Comment: wouldnt it not take out the footer out of screen if the listview is large?

Comment: @AbdulSalamAli if your data is large then better way you have to give fix `height` to `ListView` and There is no any other option if you not like this way then you have change the structure.

Comment: yes I just checked it and the footer gets out of the screen if the list view is too large in size

Comment: @AbdulSalamAli better approch you can set `Fix Height` to `ListView` and make it `Scrollable`.

Comment: isnt there a way to make a sign of plus  and entitle that if u want to see lit click here and that plus sign change into minus sign , and the layout expand down wards showing the listview , here footer can get out of screen but , when user hit the minus button that expanded layout get again collapsed and the minus sign change back to plus sign ,  and footer gets back into screen ?

Just sharing thoughts

Comment: @AbdulSalamAli I Think you are talking about this : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: no that is a expandable list view whose each item gets expanded , i want same behavior let say to linear layout , which contains listview

Comment: @AbdulSalamAli it is same see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888643/how-to-expand-and-collapse-an-item-in-listview

Comment: let see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,.. create one xml and copy paste this code and set your dialog xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_rl"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/your_items_tv"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            customFontPath="lato_black.ttf"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="HEADING"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/your_items_tv"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                    customFontPath="lato_bold.ttf"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TOP BAR"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/table_rl"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff00ff">

            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                customFontPath="lato_bold.ttf"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bottom Bar "/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```